# Icewind Dale - Heart of Winter: does finishing "Trials of the luremaster" give no XP?

Tags: icewind-dale

I've just finished the "Trials of the luremaster" quest in Icewind Dale - Heart of Winter. It looks like there are no XP granted for finishing it, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. There is no XP or loot reward. The reward is apparently just being able to leave.